# Connect to an SQL Server RDS database from a Lambda function (SAM App)?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

```
var sql = require("mssql");

const config = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password', 
    server: 'mssql-instance.cmujwb4lclgy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    database: 'mssql-instance',
    port: 1433
};

exports.clock = async(event) => {
    
    console.log('Connecting to the rds..')
    let message = "Not Connected"

    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        let sqlRequest = new sql.Request();

        let sqlQuery = "SELECT * from InexistantTable where InexistantId = 0;"

        message = "Connected"

        sqlRequest.sqlQuery(sqlQuery, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err)

            console.table(data.recordset);
            message = "Connected, attempted query."

            sql.close();
        });
    });

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify("SQL Server: " + message)
    }

    return response;
}
```

I get this log

```
2022-01-25T21:47:01.796Z    c3c94b7f-92a9-4b90-8cc4-fe208fff611a    INFO    ConnectionError: Failed to connect to mssql-instance.cmujwb4lclgy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 in 15000ms
    at /var/task/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:71:17
    at Connection.onConnect (/var/task/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1043:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Connection.emit (/var/task/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1071:18)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1530:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1475:12)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to mssql-instance.cmujwb4lclgy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 in 15000ms
      at ConnectionError (/var/task/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12)
      at Connection.connectTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1530:54)
      at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1475:12)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
    code: 'ETIMEOUT'
  }
}
```

Its in a default VPC so I thought I wouldn't need to do any security group or roles. Looking into this is quite confusing too.

If I do have to set it up, where exactly do I do it? In the VPC dashboard? Directly in the Lambda function or on the RDS Instance itself? And do I associate it with the RDS or the Lambda? Inbound or Outbound?

Also, I am using the database instance name to connect. I used another guide to create a MySQL RDS and there was an place where I also gave it a database name too, which is the one I used to connect to, but for SQL Server RDS I had no such option when setting up the express standard configuration database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making it work. The problem was not Security Group or VPC. It was the async part. Since i was returning the response to the Lambda before the connection was made, it never knew it succeeded so it timed out

I had to make sure the connection was established first, but my code feels really messy. I would like to improve it

```
const sql = require('mssql');

exports.mssql = (event, context, callback) => {

    sql.connect({
        user: 'user',
        password: 'pass',
        server: 'host',
        database: 'testdb',
        port: 1433,
    },
    err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Fail")
            callback('connect failed', err);
        } else {
            let sqlRequest = new sql.Request();
            let sqlQuery = "SELECT * from TestTable;"

            sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
                console.table(data.recordset);
                sql.close();
            });
            
            callback(null, sqlRequest);

            response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: "Query returned",
                })
            }
            return response;
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a role for the lambda. Go to(console) `IAM->Roles->Create role->(select)Lambda->(in permissions)AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole->tags->name..etc`.
Your 'Trust relationships'(after you create the role) should be similar to

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
},
"Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
]
}
```

Now go to your lambda and in `Configuration` tab, edit `Execution role` and give arn of the role you created.
**Edit**: Now in the `Configuration` tab, go to `VPC->Edit->select vpc (where your RDS is situated)->select subnet(where your RDS is situated)->select a security group(select any, maybe the one attached to the DB)*->Save`.
If I am not mistaken any security group will be fine, Lambda doesn't need whitelisting.
Further details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html). I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I made the role and all was ok, except that I'm not sure where to check the 'Trust Relationship'

I still get the same error in the log

I think now i have to Provide access to the DB instance in the VPC by creating security group.

If you could point me in the right direction to do this just like you did with the role i would be very grateful.

I would look into any additional suggestions should there be any

Comment: @SystemCyprus, edited the answer. When you open `role` in `IAM`, the second tab(after `Permissions`) is `Trust relationships`. You can click and edit. Probably you won't need to edit it.

Comment: I did not, indeed, need to edit it as it was just like you showed, which indicates this part is ok

By setting up a VPC Security group, i was able to connect from my local SSMS, which is progress, but am still unable to connect from Lambda even if i took the same steps minus giving it My IP as value.

Comment: Ok, the above answer was more for an IAM user with 'less' previlges. Open(inbound and outbound) port `1433` on the security group(let's say MYSG) of `RDS` to MYSG. Put the lambda in the same security group. If the security groups are different, open access to each other on the same port. check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-lambda-to-an-rds-instance/

Comment: For the inbound source and outbound destination, if i set it to Anywhere IPV4 it should work right? It still isn't connecting but i don't get a timeout error message anymore

Comment: @SystemCyprus, set it to the SG instead of an ip. What error do you get now? Have you tested your connection outside lambda? does it work?

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't attach the policies until now, it always gave me an error.
Was able to attach it, allowing all traffic and i chose all protocol and all port range for the time being

Did the same for outbound

But it still doesn't work

For the role policies, i have AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole and AmazonRDSFullAccess and AmazonRDSDataFullAccess and AWSClodFormationFullAccess but i think they are all useless eccept the first. And those are attached to the Lambda Permissions Role

But the Lambda VPC has the same SG as the rds itself (using the same inbound/outbound rules) :S

Comment: @SystemCyprus, is your `RDS` in private or public subnet? Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html for your case.

Comment: here are some screenshots to better show what i have so far [link](http://expand.mydiscussion.net). I am not sure about the subnet group. The instance says YES to Available Publicly and there are 2 subnet groups one who has us-east-1a to f availability zones with their cidr block, but I'm not even if it's public

Comment: @SystemCyprus Can you remove `default(SG)` from RDS? Do you have any `EC2` in the same `subnet`? Can you try to login to `RDS` from that `EC2`?

Comment: Is your endpoint correct? `dig` or `nslookup` doesn't find it..

Comment: Yes I can remove the Default SG. And am able to log into the RDS from EC2 (I think) and i assume that means they are in the same subnet

I Was even able to connect to the RDS from my local SSMS (after configuring an Inbound rule)

Comment: The RDS endpoint? I assume so, if i am able to connect to it from local SSMS using the right port. ssms-instance.cmujwb4lclgy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

Comment: At this point i think it would make sense to open a ticket with AWS. I will make sure to come back here and detail the steps taken to make it all work.

Comment: `mssql-instance.cmujwb4lclgy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` is not valid which you have given in your question while the one you gave now`(ssms-instance.cmujwb4lclgy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com)` is valid domain.